# Прокрутка текста

Tags: unity3d, текст

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Доброго времени суток. Прошу прощения, если вопрос глупый. С Английским пока немного туго и на форуме Unity3d не нашёл ответа на свой вопрос, быть может найду ответ здесь: "Как сделать так, чтобы текст можно было проматывать в области двух толстых линий? Т.е., общий объем текста больше области, выделенной двумя линиями, и необходимо, чтобы в этой области его можно было промотать. Речь идёт о тачскрине, не о PC."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В Unity для этого есть UI компонент [Scroll View](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-ScrollRect.html). Настраивается там всё просто.

Вот вам [официальный тутор](https://unity3d.com/ru/learn/tutorials/topics/user-interface-ui/scroll-view)

А ПК это или мобилка - роли не играет. Всё внутри Unity работает на получении определённых команд ввода - эти команды выдаёт Input Module. А что именно он превращает в команды - зависит от типа модуля (Standalone или Touch).